# Stretching of QGIS symbols

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am trying to create symbol in QGIS using svg. When I place the point in QGIS it symbology remains same.

1. Is there any possibility to stretch the symbol in QGIS?
2. Can we make stretchable point symbols in QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define the size in map units (often meters) rather than mm or pixels. The size of the symbology on your screen will then vary according to the level of zoom.

You might want to use a size depending on a field in your layer: in this case just select the icon next to the size of the symbology and select the field you want to use.

You might want to use an expression (icon next to the size of the symbology and select expression), which could be based on anything, including the scale of your zoom, using  @map_scale for example.

You could use a rule-based symbology and define a different size of symbology for different scales: right click on the symbology (once rule-based selected) => Refine current rule => Add scale to rules.

If you want to stretch a point, you should use an ellipse with a width dependent on scale but not the height.

The only way I have found to *stretch* a svg would be to use *draw effect* (at the bottom of the style window) => Transform (as effet type) => and scale. However, it seems it is not possible to make those transformations field or expression dependent.

In rule-based it seems to be possible to add draw effects per symbology (e.g. per scale) and you could therefore define different *stretches* for different scales for the same symbol. However, it does not seem to work on my computer.

There are many options.

Comment: For SVG symbol the size is divided on Width and Height, both of these properties could be data defined so it's easy to "stretch" horizontally or vertically at last