# Filling polygon with graphic file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, style, fill

What I want to do is to fill a polygon (country) with a graphic file in any format (*.jpg, *.bmp*, *.png*).

It should look like this:

[image]

I'm aware that GIS soft is not proper for such an operation but maybe is there any option to do it only in QGIS.

Comment: Convert your image to SVG format then in `Layer Properties > Style`, change the _Simple fill_ layer type option to _SVG fill_. You can look at this post to see how to import your svg files into QGIS: [Importing SVG symbols into QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/importing-svg-symbols-into-qgis)

Comment: Seems it work fine, the only problem is to fit the flag into polygon.

Comment: Yes, I too have that problem sometimes. Perhaps this post might help: [Stretching of QGIS symbols](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213634/stretching-of-qgis-symbols)

Answer (score 10):

Use the "raster image fill" style on the polygon layer. This fill style allows drawing a polygon using a PNG/JPG/BMP/... etc.

Answer (score 7):

Using a gradient, you can obtain this:

[image: Result]

[image: Gradient settings]

You have to use two stops at the border between colours, one for each colour, to make sure the result is neat.
SVG would in any case be the way to go for any flag with more than straight lines!

Comment: to _force_ discrete gradient, put one stop at 33.2% (in this case, black) and the other one in 33.3% (red). Do the same with 66.5% and 66.6% (red and yellow, respectively).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Python by creating image patches and clipping images using the patches. Needs Python libraries like shapely, cartopy and GeoPandas.
[here](https://deepaksatheesan.com/filling-shapefile-polygons-with-images-gis-visualization-using-python/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).